Twilio interaction API error: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Routing is invalid
I'm trying to send an outbound WhatsApp Message using the code in this twilio docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/conversations/send-outbound-messages-via-sms-and-whatsapp#outbound-whatsapp
My code is exactly the same as the example the only different is I changed parameters.
Here is the code:
$interaction = $this->client->flexApi->v1->interaction->create(
         [
            "type" => "whatsapp",
            "initiated_by" => "agent",
            "properties" => [
               "type" => "whatsapp",
            ],
            "participants" => [
               [
                  "address" => "whatsapp:$to",
                  "proxy_address" => "whatsapp:" . env('OUTBOUND_MX_WHATSAPP_PHONE_NUMBER'),
                  "type" => "whatsapp",
               ],
            ],
         ], // channel
         [
            "routing" => [
               "properties" => [
                  "workspace_sid" => env('TWILIO_WORKSPACE_SID'),
                  "workflow_sid" => env('TWILIO_MX_WORKFLOW_SID'),
                  "queue_sid" => env('TWILIO_MX_QUEUE_SID'),
                  "worker_sid" => $worker->sid,
                  "attributes" => [
                     "customerName" => "John Doe",
                     "customerAddress" => "whatsapp:$to",
                  ],
               ],
            ],
         ]
      );

But no matter what workflow/queue/worker I used it keeps giving me back this error: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Routing is invalid
The Twilio error code is 45008 but that does not yield useful information.
I tried creating an agent initiated conversation via WhatsApp but I got an error instead.

That's a request error (like a malformed request), so what exactly was it you changed?

Have you checked what data you are actually sending there? Replace the ...->create call with a var_dump, and then check if all those parameters are actually set to the values you intended.

Thanks, for the comments I actually found that the Twilio documentation is wrong and the "routing" key must be remove from array. It should just be "properties".
